# Cannot create javascript class in Domino Designer script library

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to create a Javascript library in Domino Designer, which will contain a number of classes and functions for use in multiple places (it is intended to be a translation of an existing Lotusscript library, with the intention of using the same code for rich and web clients).

On creating a class:

```
class TestClass {}
```

...and attempting to save, I get the message "class is a reserved identifier".

There must be a way to define classes, surely?!
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, everything in javascript is really an object, so another identifier can be used instead.  Domino Designer will not accept the word "class" to define a class, but define it as a function instead (with further functions inside as methods) and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to define a class in JavaScript that are well documented [here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/). All of them work as expected in Domino Designer for both Client Side JS and Server Side JS code. You probably want the first since it sounds like you need multiple instances of the object defined by the class.